# Properly leave a chat room in smack Android

Tags: android, chat, smack, asmack

In my appilcation I am using below method to leave from a chat room.

```
 public void leaveChatRoom(String username)
{
    Log.i("XMPP Chat Client", "User left chat room ");
    if(groupChat != null && groupChat.isJoined())
    {
        try {
            Presence leavePresence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
            leavePresence.setTo("groupchat@conference.xxx/" + username);
            connection.sendPacket(leavePresence);
            groupChat.leave();


        } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And to check whether the user is joined or not,

```
public boolean isJoinedGroup(String username)
    {
        boolean isConnected = false;
        if(groupChat != null && groupChat.isJoined())
        {
            isConnected = true;
            Log.i("XMPP Chat Client", "Joined True");
        }
        return isConnected;
}
```

This works fine if there is a successful chat server connection. But in some cases chat server connection loses. In that situation, I have to make the user leave from chat room and join back again automatically. So when I lose chat server connection, I will reconnect to chat server and call `leaveChatRoom` method and `join group` method together. I am getting `NotConnectedException` in line `groupChat.leave();` and when I check joined status,it always returns true. When I checked openfire admin panel, there is no user in groupchat occupants list. How can I properly remove user from groupchat in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

leave a chat room in smack Android - Kotlin

```
override fun leaveGroup(roomId: String, username: String) {
    if (connection.isConnectionEstablished()) {
        try {
            val mucJid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("${roomId}.@conference.yourhost/${username}")
            val jid = JidCreate.from("${roomId}.@conference.yourhost/${username}")


            val manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection)
            val muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(mucJid)

            if (!muc.isJoined) {
                val nickName = Resourcepart.from(phone)
                muc.join(nickName)
            }


            val leavePresence = PresenceBuilder.buildPresence().ofType((Presence.Type.unavailable)).build()
            leavePresence.to = jid
            connection.sendStanza(leavePresence)
            muc.leave()

         
        } catch (e: NoResponseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: XMPPErrorException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: NotConnectedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```